# Writing a LEFT JOIN

Tags: 8, database

I have the following raw SQL:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM node_field_data n
 LEFT JOIN book b ON n.nid=b.nid
 WHERE n.type IN ('book')
 AND (b.has_children != 1 OR b.nid IS NULL)
```

I have a module that I need to add this query to, so I already have a $query object.  The problem I'm having is finding the documentation/syntax to do the 
LEFT JOIN part of my query.

This is what I've added to `$query`.

```
 $query->addWhere(0,'node.nid', 'b.nid');
 $query->addWhere(0,$types,'IN');
 $query->addWhere(0,'b.has_children',1,'<>');
 $query->addWhere(1,'b.nid','IS NULL');
```

How do I add the `LEFT JOIN` part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method is actually named [`leftJoin`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Database!Query!SelectInterface.php/function/SelectInterface%3A%3AleftJoin/8.2.x):

```
$query->leftJoin('book', 'b', 'n.nid = b.nid');
```

Comment: Found that and your answer at the same time.  Going to mark it as such.  Still getting no results, but better than earlier when I was getting errors.  Is there a way to print out the query using logger?

Comment: Casting to a string should get you the query string, e.g. `(string) $query`

Comment: ugh. So I'm getting a this when I try to execute this statement:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\Sql::leftJoin()

This is the snippet of code I'm trying to implement

         $query->leftJoin('book', 'b', 'node.nid = b.nid');
         $query->addWhere(0,'book,article','IN');
         $query->addWhere(0,'b.has_children',1,'<>');
         $query->addWhere(1,'b.nid','IS NULL');